# How to find text alignment inside WinCell?

Tags: c#, winforms

I'm testing UI of one program built using WinForms. 
Using CodedUI library I read objects from WinForms and then verify they appear as given in requirements.
I need to verify the alignment within WinCells inside WinTable (i.e. is text inside these WinCells right/left aligned?).

Is there a way to find text alignment inside WinCell or WinTable?
[Screenshot of a problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DU2wu.png)

Thanks in advance!

I tried converting WinTable to DataGridView object, but it seems that data is not passed to DataGridView from my WinTable. I believe such conversion is not supported.

```cs
WinTable winTable = new WinTable(winWindow2) { TechnologyName = "MSAA" };
winTable.SearchProperties.Add(UITestControl.PropertyNames.ControlType, "Table");
winTable.SearchProperties.Add(UITestControl.PropertyNames.Name, "DataGridView");
winTable.SearchProperties.Add(UITestControl.PropertyNames.ControlType, "Table");

BindingSource bs = new BindingSource();
bs.DataSource = winTable;
DataGridView dataGridView = new DataGridView();
dataGridView.DataSource = bs;
```

Comment: The major problem comes from the fact that CodedUI "cannot see" Cell style/alignment properties by UIMap. Hence, we cannot see such information about the cell directly using UITestControl.PropertyNames command.